# select specific columns in Spark DataFrames from Array of Struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a Spark DataFrame `df` with the following Schema:

```
root
 |-- k: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- v: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- b: double (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

Is it possible to just select `a, c` in `v` from `df` without doing a `map`?  In particular, `df` is loaded from a Parquet file and I don't want the values for `c` to even be loaded/read.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what you expect as an output, which is not clear from your question. Let me clarify.
You can do

```
df.select($"v.a",$"v.b").show()
```

however, the result may be not what you want, since `v` is an array, it will yield an array for a and one per b. What you may want to do is `explode` the array v then select from the exploded dataframe:

```
df.select(explode($"v").as("v" :: Nil )).select($"v.a", $"v.b").show()
```

this will flatten v to a table with all its values flattened.
In either case, spark/parquet *should* be smart enough to use predicate push down and not load c at all.