# Extract columns in nested Spark DataFrame as scala Arrays

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame `myDf` which contains an array of pairs of points (i.e. x and y coordinates), it has the following schema:

```
myDf.printSchema

root
 |-- pts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: float (nullable = true)
```

I want to get `x` and `y` as individual plain Scala `Array`'s. I think I need to apply the explode-function, but I cannot figure out how. I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172254/select-specific-columns-in-spark-dataframes-from-array-of-struct) solution but I cant get it to work.

I'm using Spark 1.6.1 with Scala 2.10

EDIT: I realize that I had a misunderstanding how Spark works, getting the actual arrays is only possible if the data is collected (or using UDFs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get the points as plan scala Arrays:

collecting to the driver:

```
val localRows = myDf.take(10)
val xs: Array[Float] = localRows.map(_.getAs[Float]("x"))
val ys: Array[Float] = localRows.map(_.getAs[Float]("y"))
```

or inside an UDF:

```
val processArr = udf((pts:WrappedArray[Row]) => {

  val xs: Array[Float] = pts.map(_.getAs[Float]("x")).array
  val ys: Array[Float] = pts.map(_.getAs[Float]("y")).array
  //...do something with it
})
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `myDf` is `DataFrame` read from a `json` file:

```
{
 "pts":[
    {
     "x":0.0,
     "y":0.1
    },
    {
     "x":1.0,
     "y":1.1
    },
    {
     "x":2.0,
     "y":2.1
    }
  ]
}
```

You can do `explode` like this:

**Java:**

```
DataFrame pts = myDf.select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(df.col("pts")).as("pts"))
                    .select("pts.x", "pts.y");
pts.printSchema();
pts.show();
```

**Scala:**

```
// Sorry I don't know Scala
// I just interpreted from the above Java code
// Code here may have some mistakes
val pts = myDf.select(explode($"pts").as("pts"))
              .select($"pts.x", $"pts.y")
pts.printSchema()
pts.show()
```

Here is the printed schema:

```
root
 |-- x: double (nullable = true)
 |-- y: double (nullable = true)
```

And here is the `pts.show()` result:

```
+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|0.0|0.1|
|1.0|1.1|
|2.0|2.1|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks to both the questioner and the answerer. You guys made my day. I was pulling off my hair when using spark-xml and your solution rocks ;-)